# firebase_messaging >=7.0.3 <8.0.0-dev.7 is forbidden. Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-storage

I want to add `firebase_messaging` package to my flutter app, but when I install it, an error appeared which is:

```
Because firebase_messaging >=7.0.3 <8.0.0-dev.7 depends on firebase_core ^0.5.0+1 and elderly_app depends on firebase_core ^0.7.0, firebase_messaging >=7.0.3 <8.0.0-dev.7 is forbidden.
So, because elderly_app depends on firebase_messaging 7.0.3, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because elderly_app depends on firebase_messaging 7.0.3, version solving failed.)
```

I have tried to install two versions of `firebase_messaging` , they are :

`firebase_messaging: ^9.0.0` and `firebase_messaging: 7.0.3`
and also the same error appeard.

These are my `dependencies` in `pubspec.yaml` :

```
dependencies:


  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  flutter_localizations:
      sdk: flutter
  ff_navigation_bar: ^0.1.5
  calendar_timeline: ^0.7.0
  date_time_picker: "^1.1.1"
  firebase_core: ^0.7.0
  firebase_auth: ^0.20.0+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.16.0
  modal_progress_hud: ^0.1.3
  datetime_picker_formfield: ^1.0.0
  adhan: ^1.1.14
  image_picker: ^0.6.7+22
  syncfusion_flutter_calendar: ^18.4.42
  geolocator: ^6.2.1
  fluttertoast: ^7.1.6
  geocoder: ^0.2.1
  some_calendar: ^1.2.6
  flutter_calendar_week:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/mduccc/flutter_calendar_week
      ref: 0.1.0
  bubble: ^1.1.9+1
  firebase_storage: ^7.0.0
  charts_flutter: ^0.9.0
  firebase_messaging: 7.0.3
```

Comment: Check this : https://pratikbutani.medium.com/flutter-2-upgrade-flutter-version-solving-failed-error-33ac1087cb6b

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try removing the version number and use it like this:

```
firebase_messaging:
```

Answer (score 1):

You must update the core version, also keep all firebase products up to dated,
use the following latest release or you will face a lot of problems:

```
  firebase_messaging: ^9.0.0
  firebase_core: ^1.0.1
  firebase_auth: ^1.0.1
  cloud_firestore: ^1.0.1
```

you can get to know the updates on every package you use by running 'flutter pub outdated'